# What does this combination of :before, :after and display:table do?

Tags: html, css

I have been digging into a CSS sheet of good quality.

The author uses a lot of expressions like these:

```
.clearfix:after, 
.clearfix:before, 
.product-slogan:after, 
.product-slogan:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
```

I understand what `:after`,  `content`, `display` do but I don't understand the meaning of what they achieve together.

I observe that the layout changes substantially, if I switch off some of these `display: table`. It seems, they can alter the layout behavior of nested `<div>` boxes, e.g. if one box is `float: left` and it's parent is not, then the parent's height won't adopt to the child's hight. But with this `content` and `display` definition, the height will adopt, although the child itself is not `display:table`.

So the question is: Can somebody tell some details or context about this "trick"? Is it a "hack", like the famous "star hack", or is it something quiet obvious I just don't see right now?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is part of a micro clearfix hack described in details here: [nicolasgallagher.com: A new micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

> The clearfix hack is a popular way to contain floats without resorting to using presentational markup.[...]

The complete clearfix is:

```
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

> [...]This “micro clearfix” generates pseudo-elements and sets their display to table. This creates an anonymous table-cell and a new block formatting context that means the :before pseudo-element prevents top-margin collapse. The :after pseudo-element is used to clear the floats. As a result, there is no need to hide any generated content and the total amount of code needed is reduced.[...]

Comment: @peter_the_oak there are different clear fix solutions out there, which one you want to use depends on the situation. Because they have different advantages/disadvantages.

Comment: @peter_the_oak Well the high rep does not help that much. At least I don't care that much about it. There are  profiles around here with a 10k+ rep that give wrong or inaccurate answers and only got that rep because of the many answers they gave and not cause of the quality. Luckily enough I can distinguish between good and bad answers when I am looking for answers myself.